# Point S3 bucket to top level domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-s3

I'm able to point a custom bucket named media.example.com to http://s3.amazonaws.com/media.example.com by creating a dns entry media > cname > http://s3.amazonaws.com/media.example.com on my example.com server.

My question is, can you point a top level domain and if so how do you set it up in the DNS?

That is if I create a bucket called, example.com (no subdomain) and in the DNS would I do a cname still and leave the first box empty, select cname for type? Or do I have to point it to a subdomain such as "www" or should it be an a record instead of a cname, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point an S3 bucket to a top level domain but it is a bit complex. Using your example, you should redirect example.com to www.example.com through your DNS provider or through a third-party service. This will give you the IP address that will be the A record for your top level domain, and your www record is configured as cname. So basically you create your cname record as you would in a regular case and just add the www to your subdomain. Just remember that your bucket name and subdomain must be the same and your records must be the same at all levels or else any redirection might result in unexpected behavior.

Hope this clears it up a bit… Lena ;-)